# What does the (): {} mean in typescript

Tags: typescript

In abc.ts, I have

```
export const getTerms = (): {
    aliceExpectedAmount: number;
    bobExpectedAmount: number;
} => {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./terms.json`) as unknown as string);
}
```

and in terms.json I have

```
{
  "aliceExpectedAmount": 3,
  "bobExpectedAmount": 5
}
```

This function `getTerms` (cuz it's indicated by `()`) parses the `terms.json` and hydrates the data (of type `any`) into the struct defined after `:`. I don't know what kind of syntax it is. Is it something like a named return?

Thank you for any explanation :p I know this is a silly question but I just haven't figured it out

Comment: this is just the return type of the function

Comment: It means that the function `getTerms` returns a specific [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types)